# Parametrize the after operator in drools

Tags: drools

i have a fairly simple question, i have this rule

```
rule 'Rule1'
    when  
        $inMess : MetaMessage()
        not(MetaMessage(this after[0, 10000] $inMess, this != $inMess))
    then  
        log.info("Message id:"+ $inMess.getId());
end
```

It works perfectly (in the after operand, if you use only a number it assumes milliseconds), i have only one other thing to do, parametrize the after operator so it can accept a property of the MetaMessage.

Something like this

```
rule 'Rule1'
    when  
        $inMess : MetaMessage($delay : delay)
        not(MetaMessage(this after[0, $delay] $inMess, this != $inMess))
    then  
        log.info("Message id:"+ $inMess.getId());
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: I immagined as much, but i hoped i was wrong :(

I'll see if i can find a different approach, thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas